# Why is there a factor of $\pi$ in the average velocity of gas?

Tags: kinetic-theory

Consider the most probable and RMS speeds for a kinetic gas:
$$ v_{mps} = \sqrt{\frac{2RT}{M}}$$

$$ v_{rms} = \sqrt{ \frac{3RT}{M}}$$

Now consider the average speed:

$$ v_{avg} = \sqrt{\frac{8RT}{\pi M}}$$

Why does a factor of $\pi$ pop up in the above equation? I know the mathematical reason is due to integrations of gaussian integrals but usually $\pi$ we associate with circles/spheres. So, is there a physical way to give meaning as to why we should expect a $\pi$ in the formula here?

[Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/629550/intuition-behind-order-of-speeds-in-kinetic-gas-theory)

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28558 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3239012

Comment: What does mps stand for?

Comment: Most probable speed @J.G.

Comment: @Buraian I was typing this question and then saw yours .. +1..

Comment: Greats minds think alike @Ankit

Comment: I agree with Al-brown in the answer below that the question is more why the $\pi$ is missing in the other expressions. It should come as no surprise that $\pi$ appears given that we both are dealing with Gaussian integrals *and* averages over all of space of a *spherically* symmetric distribution. The cancellations in the other expressions are merely mathematical. A less trivial question would be why the Maxwell distribution is the way it is. Maxwell's geometric explanation of that fact can be found here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.01411.pdf.

Comment: I was just about to write that a more interesting question might be why there is a pi in the velocity pdf to begin with. Sondre seems to be saying basically same

Comment: @sondre yes agree per above. Also T and p both come from velocity. (p from elastic collision model)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the $\pi$ term in the given $f_V(v)$, the question is not so much where the $\pi$ comes from in $v_{avg}$, but rather, “Where does the $\pi$ go in the others?”

First, note the $\pi$ term in our velocity pdf:
$$f_p(v)=4 \pi v^2 (\frac{1}{\pi} \frac{m}{2k_bT})^{1.5} \exp(\frac{-mv^2}{2k_bT}) $$ $$ f_p(v)=  j \frac{v^2}{\sqrt{\pi}}  \exp(-kv^2)$$

$$\text{with }~k \equiv \frac{m}{2k_bT} ~,~ j\equiv 4k^{1.5}$$

First, it’s disappearing from $v_{mp}$ is maximization:

---

1.$v_{mp}$: The most probable speed is determined by setting the derivative of the pdf equal to zero (We are finding the maximum density point):

$$ \frac{\partial f_p}{\partial v} = \frac{j}{\sqrt{\pi}} (2v e^{-kv^2} -2kv^3 e^{-kv^2})=0$$

$$\implies \frac{2 j v e^{-kv^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} (1-kv^2)=0$$

The resulting $v_{mp}=\operatorname{argmax}[f_p(\cdot)]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}= \sqrt{\frac{2k_bT}{m}}$ does not include a $\pi$.

---

2.Now for $v_{avg}$, where the $\pi$, perhaps unsurprisingly, ends up as a radical in the denominator, as it is in the distribution. $$v_{avg} = \int vf_p(v)dv$$

With a very minor notation abuse.

$$ v_{avg}= \frac{j}{\sqrt{\pi}}   \int  v^3 \exp(-kv^2)dv$$

Based in this link from Vincent Thacker in the comments https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28558 , we see a $\pi$ *will not* appear with an exponent of $3$, hence the original $f_V(v)$’s $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ *will* go through to the $v_{avg}$.

Specifically:

$$ v_{avg}= \frac{j}{\sqrt{\pi}}   \int  v^3  ~ e^{-kv^2}dv$$

$$v_{avg}= \frac{-j}{2k^2\sqrt{\pi}}(kv^2+1) e^{-kv^2}  \Big|_0^{\infty}$$

$$= 0 - \frac{-4k^{1.5}}{2k^2\sqrt{\pi}} ~ \cdot 1=\frac{2}{\sqrt{k \pi}} =\sqrt{\frac{8k_bT}{\pi m}}$$

---

3.Consider the $f_p(v)$ to $f_p(v^2)$ general transition with $x,y$: Note that $$F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(X^2\leq y)=P(X\leq\sqrt{y})=F_X(\sqrt{y})=\int_0^\sqrt{y}3t^2\,dt=y^{3/2}$$ hence $$f_Y(y)=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{y}\implies v^4$$

Based again in this link from Vincent Thacker in the comments https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28558 , we see a $\sqrt{\pi}$ *will* appear in the numerator with an exponent of $4$, hence the original $f_V(v)$’s $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ *will not* be in the expressions for $v_{rms}^2$ and then $v_{rms}$.

Comment: Nice.. but this is again mathematical

Comment: Theres lots of words in there saying what the source of the pi is.

Comment: I have upvoted both answers, but I'll wait a bit more and see if I other answers. However, I do understand your point that the question should be why the pi doesn't appear there. Maybe there is something fundamental being missed.

Comment: Yes makes sense. I did think more about why intuitively pi is there. Did you see my last comment about not a circle but rather normal curve kicking out a pi, under other answer? Also, for $v_{mp}$, there is the reminder that pi never is part of the mean. If x is normal, I think E(x^3) and E(x^5) have a pi? If time I might write something on that in answer. Question actually does make lotta sense and I at least upvoted. Not even sure ours is guassian but gotta roll..

Answer (score 2):

OP is asking for prose description of my other answer saying where the $\pi$ came from. So here that is - the prose part of the other answer expanded, plus a couple summary sentences at the end (jump to that if you wish):

---

Based on the $\pi$ term in the given $f_p(v)$, the question is not so much where the $\pi$ comes from in $v_{avg}$, but rather, “Where does the $\pi$ go in the others?”

First, note the $\pi$ term in our velocity pdf: $$f_p(v)=4 \pi v^2 (\frac{1}{\pi} \frac{m}{2k_bT})^{1.5} \exp(\frac{-mv^2}{2k_bT}) $$ If we plug in constants for the unchanging stuff and simplify, the $\pi$ becomes a radical in the denominator and the functional form is easier to see: $$ f_p(v)=  (\tfrac{j}{\sqrt{\pi}}) ~ v^2  e^{-kv^2}$$

Where did this $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ go in two of our answers? After all, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ appears exactly in $v_{avg}$. Why not in $v_{mp}$ and $v_{rms}$?

First, it’s disappearing from $v_{mp}$ is due to maximization.

---

1.$v_{mp}$: The most probable speed is determined by setting the derivative of the pdf equal to zero (We are finding the maximum density point):

The resulting $v_{mp}=\operatorname{argmax}$ does not include a $\pi$.

Generally when you maximize, the constants out front dont matter. They don’t affect the maximizing value $x^*$ that you pick. Whatever maximizes some $f(x)$ also maximizes $k ~f(x)$. So it’s unsurprising to not see a $k$ in the result.

That’s true in our maximization. Meaning $k$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ here. So that explains why the $\pi$ term disappeared from the given pdf when finding $v_{mp}$. We didn’t actually integrate any $f_p$ form like with the other two, just picked a $v$ to maximize it.

2.Now for $v_{avg}$, where the $\pi$, perhaps unsurprisingly, ends up as a radical in the denominator, *as it is in the distribution* function $f_p$, because: $$v_{avg} = \int vf_p(v)dv$$

Based on this link from Vincent Thacker in the comments https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28558 for how to integrate that, we see a $\pi$ *will not* appear just from integrating with an exponent of $3$ (the $\int v^3 e^{-kv} dv$ form), hence the original $f_p(v)$’s $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ *will* go through to the $v_{avg}$. Because integrating did not create a $\pi$ to cancel it out.

3.Based again on the link for how to integrate that, we see a $\sqrt{\pi}$ *will* appear in the numerator with an exponent of $4$, (the $\int v^4 e^{-kv} dv$ form), and that is available to cancel out, hence the original $f_p(v)$’s $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ *will not* be in the expressions for $v_{rms}^2$ and then $v_{rms}$.

In Summary, the given pdf for the velocity had a $\sqrt{\pi}$ in the denominator, so it was initially surprising to not see it in all three results. For $v_{mp}$, the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ was a leading coefficient which did not affect the selection of the pdf’s maximizing $v$ (where the slope is zero). For $v_{rms}$, it disappeared because integration of a form $\int v^4 e^{-kv} dv$ creates a $\sqrt{\pi}$ as a result, canceling the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ in $f_p$.

Comment: I accept this , but, your answer is not from the angle I wanted the question to be answered in

Comment: It’s the only possible answer. Integrating a $\int v^4 e^{-kv}$ form makes a $\pi$ appear as a mathematical result, which cancels the given $\pi$. Thats why it left $v_{rms}$. Again, it leaving the given pdf is what should be the confusion. Not the fact that youre given a pdf with it there and it ends up in your answer.

Comment: I would say that the pi is not about circles but is about the normal curve for $f_p(v)$. Have a good week

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate $I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx e^{-x^2}$ the trick is often to evaluate
$$
I^2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx dy e^{-x^2}e^{-y^2}= 
2\pi \int_{0}^\infty \rho e^{-\rho^2} = \pi
$$
after the change to plane polar coordinates, so that $I=\sqrt{\pi}$.  The $\pi$ factor comes from integrating over the polar angles.

A lot of non-zero Gaussian integrals contain $\sqrt{\pi}$ factor since they can be obtained by parametric differentiation w/r to $\lambda$ of the basic result
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\lambda x^2}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}\, ,
\end{align}
*v.g*.
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d\lambda}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\lambda x^2}=
-\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 e^{-\lambda x^2}
=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\lambda^{3/2}}\, ,
\end{align}

Comment: The OP has already told us that he knows how the expression is derived.

Comment: @garyp well I'm not sure that *stating* this come from Gaussian integrals is same as knowing, and if the OP does know then it hardly makes sense to ask the question in the first place...

Comment: I guess it's how you read the post.  My interpretation of the question is:  what does average speed have to do with circles?  (And why not the others.)  The linked answers in the comment to the OP go there.  Whether or not they *get* there can be debated.

Comment: @garyp it seems you were likely right…